# How to apply group by on pyspark dataframe and a transformation on the resulting object

Tags: json, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have a spark data frame

```
| item_id | attribute_key| attribute_value
____________________________________________________________________________
| id_1        brand          Samsung
| id_1        ram            6GB
| id_2        brand          Apple
| id_2        ram            4GB
_____________________________________________________________________________
```

I want to group this data frame by `item_id` and output as a file with each line being a `json` object

```
{id_1: "properties":[{"brand":['Samsung']},{"ram":['6GB']} ]}
{id_2: "properties":[{"brand":['Apple']},{"ram":['4GB']} ]}
```

This is a big distributed data frame so , converting to pandas is not an option.
Is this kind of transformation even possible in pyspark

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In scala, but python version will be very similar (sql.functions):

```
val df = Seq((1,"brand","Samsung"),(1,"ram","6GB"),(1,"ram","8GB"),(2,"brand","Apple"),(2,"ram","6GB")).toDF("item_id","attribute_key","attribute_value")

+-------+-------------+---------------+
|item_id|attribute_key|attribute_value|
+-------+-------------+---------------+
|      1|        brand|        Samsung|
|      1|          ram|            6GB|
|      1|          ram|            8GB|
|      2|        brand|          Apple|
|      2|          ram|            6GB|
+-------+-------------+---------------+

df.groupBy('item_id,'attribute_key)
.agg(collect_list('attribute_value).as("list2"))
.groupBy('item_id)
.agg(map(lit("properties"),collect_list(map('attribute_key,'list2))).as("prop"))
.select(to_json(map('item_id,'prop)).as("json"))
.show(false)
```

output:

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------+
|json                                                              |
+------------------------------------------------------------------+
|{"1":{"properties":[{"ram":["6GB","8GB"]},{"brand":["Samsung"]}]}}|
|{"2":{"properties":[{"brand":["Apple"]},{"ram":["6GB"]}]}}        |
+------------------------------------------------------------------+
```